# Controls not showing while loading form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to Load the form as

```
Dim f as New Form2
f.show()
```

The form is getting loaded but it doesnt show all the controls. I have two buttons and two text box. Both the buttons and one text box appears as transparent. The form appears like that till the current subroutine has ended.

Moreover, the form on loading shall display the text fetched from database and shall display the text (fetched again at equal interval from db) unless user explicitly closes the application. That logic also is in Form2_Load event.

How do I write the logic such that form2 displays properly and gets the text from db at regular interval.

I am creating a dictionary like application for healthcare domain. It works in two mode. One of the mode is ribbon mode, where a form is created (the form is marked as topmost) which should display the term and definition as long as application is alive. Hence you see an endless loop. Once user presses the close button or presses X, the application will close.

I was playing around with the code and moved it from Load even to shown event. However the issue persists.

```
Private Sub Form2_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
 Handles MyBase.Shown

    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim idSelected, queryGetWordDef, totalRows
    Dim rowReturned, queryGetMaxID, provider, ipath, dataFile, connString As String
    Dim dict() As String
    Dim dr1 As OleDbDataReader
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="

    ipath = Application.StartupPath

    dataFile = ipath & "\Database\database1.mdb" ' Change it to your Access Database location

    connString = provider & dataFile

    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString

    queryGetMaxID = "SELECT ID FROM Table1"
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(queryGetMaxID, myConnection)
    Try
        dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try

    dt.Load(dr1)

    totalRows = dt.Rows.Count

    While True
        idSelected = dt.Rows.Item(CInt(totalRows * Rnd()) + 1)(0)
        queryGetWordDef = "SELECT Word & ""@"" & Meaning FROM Table1 WHERE ID = " & CStr(idSelected)

        cmd = New OleDbCommand(queryGetWordDef, myConnection)
        Try
            rowReturned = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try

        dict = rowReturned.Split("@")

        Me.txtBoxDefinition.Text = dict(1)
        Me.txtBoxTerm.Text = dict(0)


        Thread.Sleep(5000)

    End While

End Sub
```

Picture of form attached for more clarity.

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the code for the form 2?

Comment: The controls are there, they are simply not painted.  Your UI thread is doing something else it should not be doing.  Like querying the database or trying to handle a massive storm of invoke requests.  The kind of bug that requires looking at code, not a screenshot.

Comment: @HansPassant , I have updated the code in my original post. Please let me know, if something else is needed from my end.

Comment: @Karlta05, I have updated the code in my original post. Please let me know, if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you have an infinite loop. The loop is entered before the form is completed being created.

To achieve what you are requesting you need to look at [backgroundworker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can use this in conjunction with the timer to trigger the backgrounderworker doWork() event.

The link also has an example of how to update the text on a form as well.

Comment: Thanks for help.Thanks to you and stackoverflow, I learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

You have an endless loop in your `Shown` event handler.  That code is executed on the UI thread and it never ends, so you can never do anything else on the UI thread.

Get rid of that loop altogether.  If you want to do something every 5 seconds then use a `Timer` with an `Interval` of 5000.

Comment: Ok, i should have given the context before pasting the code. I am creating a dictionary like application for healthcare domain. It works in two mode. One of the mode is ribbon mode, where a form is created (the form is marked as topmost) which should display the term and definition as long as application is alive(something similar to wordweb). Hence you see an endless loop. Once user presses the close button or presses X, the application will close.

Comment: Why not use a timer to update the term and definition (like jmcilhinney suggested), or search for terms as the user types it in, then update the definition when a term is selected?

Comment: What I said still stands.  An endless loop in any method on the UI thread is something that should NEVER happen.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I did what you suggested and it worked. Thanks to you and stackoverflow, I learnt something new.